# Wine problem - ratio and mixture

Tags: recreational-mathematics, recursive-algorithms, ratio

**Question**

$8$ litres are drawn from a cask full of wine and is then filled with water. This operation is performed three more times. The ratio of the quantity of wine now left in cask to that of the water is $256:625$. How much wine did the cask hold originally?

---

**My attempt**

$4$ times $8$ litres are drawn and filled with water. So water contain is $32$ litres. Let originally there was $x$ litres of wine.

$$x:32 = 256:625$$

solving it gives $x = 13.1072$

But the answer given is $40$

Please help me solve the question and please explain.

Comment: When we draw $8$ litres the second time (and later) we are withdrawing some of the water we put in.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. Thanks. But now it became more complicated. How to solve it?

Comment: I don't get it the English term "the ratio of the quantity of wine now left in cask to that of the water is $256:625$". Does it mean "the ratio of the quantity of wine now left in cask to the total volume is $256:625$"? If so, then I can answer your question.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey No I have correctly copied. I guess it means after mixing water 4 times with wine, the ratio between wine and water in the mixture is 256:625

Comment: Then the correct answer must be $30.098$, not $40$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Please explain

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer **assuming** that $256:625$ is the ratio of the quantity of wine now left in cask to the total volume.

Let the initial amount of wine be $x$. The purity of wine after the first drawn is $\dfrac{x-8}{x}$. Then the purity of wine after the fourth drawn is $\left(\dfrac{x-8}{x}\right)^4$. Thus
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x-8}{x}\right)^4&=\frac{256}{625}\\
\left(\frac{x-8}{x}\right)^4&=\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4\\
\frac{x-8}{x}&=\frac{4}{5}\\
x&=\large\color{blue}{40}.
\end{align}

Comment: What is the answer if the ratio is considered to the wine and water after 4th time of mixing?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, why we are deducting 15 from x?

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? How you found 15 and how after fourth drawn it's [(x-15)/x]^4?

Comment: @Vikram: Sorry, I made a mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey If the ratio is considered to be different. I mean what we discussed in the comment?

Comment: @Man_From_India See my new answer. I hope it answer your question.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey In your answer you have considered the given ratio to be  ratio of the quantity of wine now left in cask to the total volume. But in the question what it says is that it's the ratio of remaining wine and added water in the mixture after completion of operation of 4th time.

Comment: @Man_From_India Have you already looked up my new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of explaining it. Let $V$ be the initial volume of the wine. Also let $V_n$ be the volume of the wine after the $n$-th drawn. One can use a recursive formula to determine $V_n$.
$$
V_n=V_{n-1}-8\cdot\frac{V_{n-1}}{V},\tag1
$$
where $V_{n-1}$ denote the volume of wine just after the previous drawn. Rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
V_n=V_{n-1}\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right).\tag2
$$
Starting from $n=4$, we follow the recursive formula in $(2)$ until we arrive at the equation:
$$
V_4=V_0\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right)^4.\tag3
$$
But $V_0=V$, thus the volume for wine after fourth drawn is
\begin{align}
V_4&=V\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right)^4\\
\frac{V_4}{V}&=\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right)^4.\tag4
\end{align}
Again, we **assume** that $256:625$ is the ratio of the quantity of wine after fourth drawn to the total volume, then using $(4)$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{256}{625}&=\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right)^4\\
V&=\color{blue}{40}.
\end{align}

---

**Addendum :**

If $256:625$ is the ratio of the quantity of wine after fourth drawn to the water **only**, then using $(4)$ we will obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{256}{256+625}&=\left(1-\frac{8}{V}\right)^4\\
V&\approx\color{blue}{30.089}.
\end{align}
Now, the choice is yours.

Comment: @Edwardffitch: Thanks for your previous answer. It gives me a good idea to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. But I have some problem as to how you wrote the last equation 256/(256+625).

Comment: @Man_From_India Isn't it obvious that the ratio of wine to the total volume (wine + water) is $\dfrac{256}{256+625}$ since the ratio of wine to water is $\dfrac{256}{625}$? Remember, at the beginning the cask is fully contained.

Comment: yes got it. but how you made equation (1)?

Comment: @Man_From_India Start from $n=1$ and then you'll get it.

Comment: Can't understand the part 8*[V(n-1)/V] in equation #1

Comment: See @AndréNicolas's comment.

Comment: I see, but I still need assistance while framing it into equation. I mean why [V(n-1)/V]. How we are getting this?